# No X authentication info set for display ":0"

Tags: linux, xorg

I am using Fedora KDE 26, and all of a sudden, I am unable to run graphical applications as root, e.g. `kdesu gparted`.

Whenever I try running such an application, I get some error message such as:

```
No X authentication info set for display ":0"
```

I tried exporting the `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY` variables as indicated in other questions, but nothing helped. I tried rebooting the machine, but the problem persists.

Note that in the case of applications such as `gparted` this prevents the application from being run at all, since it requires superuser privileges.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that the problem was an invalid hostname setting (in `/etc/hostname`):

```
localhost.localdomain
```

This has probably been updated by some package (I am running Fedora 26 Alpha, so it's normal to expect some instability), and because X authentication takes it into account (even when running locally), this was preventing something from working.

Fixing the hostname file to contain the actual value (as required in my local network) and rebooting (probably overkill) fixed everything.

*Note*: I am posting this as "Q&A" because I spent hours trying to find the cause, and every Google result led to all sorts of questions such as "when connecting via SSH...", which was not my case, so I dismissed most of them. Running `cat ~/.Xauthority` showed `localhost.localdomain0MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-<non-printable characters>`, which eventually led me to the real issue.